Need help with Python macro in LibreOffice Calc
Been looking all over but can’t find anything that can achieve this.
I have four buttons each with a label I want to be able to Click on a button  to capture the label and insert it in another cell.
Please some one help.
Thank you

To do this in LibreOffice Calc using Python, you can create a macro that captures the label of a button when clicked and inserts it into a specific cell.
Like this:
def button_click(event):
    # Get the button that triggered the event
    button = event.Source.Model
    
    # Get the label of the button
    label = button.Label
    
    # Get the current spreadsheet
    doc = button.Parent.Parent.Parent
    sheet = doc.Sheets[0]  # Change the sheet index if needed
    
    # Set the label in a specific cell (e.g., A1)
    cell = sheet.getCellRangeByName("A1")  # Change the cell address if needed
    cell.String = label

Then assign the Macro to the Buttons.
Right-click each button in LibreOffice Calc and select Control.
In the Events tab, find the “Execute action” event.
Click the button with three dots ..., choose Assign Macro, and navigate to the Python script where you saved the button_click function.
Notice:
The script captures the label using event.Source.Model.Label.
It sets the value in a specific cell using getCellRangeByName("A1").String = label
